# Undefined variable: dataProvider

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii. while I was passing the dataprovider to a view its getting error as Undefined variable dataProvider.

#### SiteController code

```
elseif ($id=='user')  
{  
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Product');
    $this->redirect(array('site/userhome'),array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));  
}
```

#### userhome code

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view')); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

what are you doing here

```
$this->redirect(array('site/userhome'),array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

Looking at your **userhome** code, it appears as if its a view file.
You want to pass the **dataprovider** to the **view**  so why are you using **REDIRECT**.
instead you should use **render** like

```
$this->render('viewFileName',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

and **second thing**
 you need to **LEARN** about **dataprovider** a more.
 **Click** [dataprovider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)

Comment: Thank You and Sorry for that Question that may be a stupid question. Im totally stranger to Yii and PHP

Comment: No problem.. Happens with every newbie.cheers. Padhte raho...seekhte raho :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
$this->render('userhome',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

in your siteController